Do we always have to pass the seeds for a PDA in Anchor?
If I want to pass a PDA in anchor I can do it like this:
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(my_param: u32)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [my_param.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
}

Let's say that that passing all the seeds takes up a lot of space or that we want to avoid passing the seeds for some other reason. My first attempt is this, but off the top of my head this would still be insecure, since an attacker could deploy a copy of MyAccount and then reassign it to be owned by my program, which would then pass this constraint check. Is there a way to ensure an account is a PDA of my program without passing the seeds directly?
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        owner = __program_id.key(),
    )]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
}


If its all static seeds you can just save the resulting public key in the program and compare.
If its dyamic seeds you can maybe save them in an account before hand similar to what token22 transferhooks does it. And then pass in that account and check the seeds from within there against the accounts passed in the instruction and only validate the seeds from the static extra seeds account.
Smth like this:
    let account_metas = vec![
        ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_seeds(
            &[Seed::Literal {
                bytes: "white_list".as_bytes().to_vec(),
            }], // owner index (delegate PDA)
            false, // is_signer
            true,  // is_writable
        )?,
    ];

Have a look at how the token program does it. Maybe that helps:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/anchor/TransferHookWhitelist/programs/transfer-hook/src/lib.rs
